# error while trying to connect aerospike DB with kubectl command

Tags: aerospike

Hi All am getting below error while trying to connect Aerospike DB

## **kubectl exec -it v11-nk-s01-csd5g1-db-0 -n v11csd -c csd-db-aerospike -- aql --tls-enable --tls-cafile /commonoamcerts/certs/cacert.pem -h csd-db -p 3000 --tls-protocols TLSv1.2 --tls-name .com**

Seed: csd-db
User: None
Config File: /etc/aerospike/astools.conf /home/csduser/.aerospike/astools.conf
2021-12-10 05:23:40 WARN SSL_connect I/O error: 104
2021-12-10 05:23:40 WARN Failed to connect to seed csd-db 3000. AEROSPIKE_ERR_CONNECTION Socket connect failed: 192.168.51.218:3000
2021-12-10 05:23:41 WARN SSL_connect I/O error: 104
2021-12-10 05:23:41 WARN Failed to connect to seed csd-db 3000. AEROSPIKE_ERR_CONNECTION Socket connect failed: 192.168.46.40:3000
2021-12-10 05:23:42 WARN SSL_connect I/O error: 104
2021-12-10 05:23:42 WARN Failed to connect to seed csd-db 3000. AEROSPIKE_ERR_CONNECTION Socket connect failed: 192.168.2.206:3000
Error -10: Failed to connect
command terminated with exit code 255

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Default TLS port is 4333. Perhaps if you are trying to make TLS connection you might should try `-p 4333` or whatever your tls port is